# Ninja When I want to export form submissions in bulk with .csv, the csv comes up empty

Tags: php, wordpress, ninja-forms

I use ninja form on my wordpress site, when I select multiple submissions and export them as csv, the csv comes out empty. But if I select a single submission and export it, the information for that submission comes in the csv. How can I fix this problem? I want to export multiple submissions as csv.

zlib.output_compression Off,
I tried php 8.1 and 7.4 and the result is the same,
Ninja Forms Edition: 3.7.0
PHP Time Limit: 300
I installed wordpress from scratch on a different hosting and when I tried, the result was the same. I didn't install any theme, I didn't install any plugin, I just installed Ninja Form and tested it and the result was the same again

Comment: This should be submitted as a bug report directly to the developers. We can help you if you have any specific programming issue with your code, not to do bug hunting in third party code/software.

Comment: Thank you, I conveyed the problem to the developers and wanted to ask you too.